# How to check if the value of a variable has a specific character?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I'm trying to make a vimscript that will read the `.gitignore` file, return it's values as a List and check for paths that has wildcards eg: `/vim/snippets/*`, `vim/**/*`.

```
let g:ignored = readfile("/home/user/Projects/dotfiles/.gitignore")

let c=0
while c < len(g:ignored)

  let g:ignoredPath = ignored[c]
  let c += 1

  echo g:ignoredPath

endwhile
```

I want to check `g:ignored` variable for possible values with wildcards but how can I do that? I'm guessing I have to use regex in an execute or something. But I don't know the right syntax at all.

Comment: after the readfile you already have a list of all entries. You can use the `match()` function to check which item matches a certain regex

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt sorry I didn't clarrified my intention, but I want to save the matching value in a variable.. and it seems impossible using `match()` (correct me if i'm wrong) as it only returns integer.

Comment: have a look at `:h matchstr` then.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo thank you so much that did the trick! could you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Function you are searching is `matchstr` it returns the matched string or if the pattern is not found, an empty string.

For your example you should note: if the expression given to `matchstr` is a `List` the matching item is returned and the type isn't changed. So it is possible that the returned item isn't a string if your list consist of other datatypes.

but as always you can read all that in `:h matchstr`.

Note: There is also `:h matchlist` which can work with capturing groups (in vim called submatches) and `:h matchstrpost` which also returns the start and end position of the match.